# Java logging all except one

Tags: java, logging

I have the following logging.properties file:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler,java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /tmp/file.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = true 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS [%4$s] %5$s%6$s%n

fileclass = INFO, FileHandler
```

Currently everything goes to the console, plus 'fileclass' package into the file,
but I want 'fileclass' package to be excluded from the console.
I could define main package to go to the console, but the main program doesnt 
have the package.

Is it possible to have such case within logging.properties:
- Everything goes to the console, except 'fileclass' which goes to the file

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Java Util Logger but normally that's related to "Additivity" of logger.

The way to achieve what you want is, set additivity of `fileclass` logger to false (which means excluding usage of parent appenders/handlers.  Then add only the appender/handler you want for `fileclass`

The way to control additivity in Java Util Logging is by using `useParentHandlers` in your config.  So it looks like:

```
fileclass.useParentHandlers=false
fileclass = INFO, FileHandler
```

By doing so, `fileclass` logger is not going to inherit handlers of its parent, and only use whatever you set to it.

One thing to note is, because logger is hierarchical.  Therefore it will affect `fileclass` logger and all its children logger.  For example if you have a logger called `fileclass.foo`, it will also be using only the `FileHandler`, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a couple ways.

Let's assume you want to leave the default console handler.
You can remove `java.util.logging.FileHandler` from the global handlers list, thus leaving you with the following:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

This will cause all applications to log to the console. To complete your case, we must ensure 'fileclass' does not log to the console, yet does log to a file.

You can do this programmatically or declaratively:

**Programmatically**

Within the 'fileclass' app. Create a custom logger.
e.g.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileClass.class.getName());

// set logger level
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);

FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("file.log");

// Set the handler level
// NOTE: This setting will ignore INFO records sent by the logger
fileHandler.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
```

Now that you've added a `FileHandler` manually. All that is left to do is disconnect the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` from  your 'fileclass'. You can do this by calling `logger.removeHandler(consoleHandler)`, where `consoleHandler` is the instance of `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`

**Declaratively**

You can also declaratively add a file handler and disable parents and global handlers

```
# disable parents, e.g. in this case the console handler
com.some.package.useParentHandlers=false 

# add the file handler
com.some.package.logger.MyLogger.level=INFO
com.some.package.MyFileHandler.pattern=%h/CoolLog%g.log
com.some.package.handler.MyFileHandler.limit=20000000
com.some.package.handler.MyFileHandler.count=20
```

This will enable you add add a file handle specifically for that application, however it won't remove the console handler since its declared globally.

You may want to take a look at my blog posts on Java Logging:

- [understand java logging](http://cdimascio.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/java-logging-using-the-java-logging-apis/)
- [progammatically overriding logging.properties](http://cdimascio.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/how-to-programmatically-set-java-logging-defaults-and-override-these-defaults-using-logging-properties/)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, software is propriatery and cannot put java code inside :(

Comment: Hmm. You can definitely declaratively add the FileHandler specifically for that app. (I've added it to my answer). On the other hand, removing the ConsoleHandler for that specific app...

Comment: it is seldom a right choice to configure logging frameworks programmatically.  Most of such normal usage scenario are possible to be controlled in corresponding configs.